# Como eliminar un nodo cuando hay mas de dos nodos DEV c++

Tags: java, c++, dev-c++, visual-c++

EN EL COMENTARIO AÑADI EL CODIGO --->
Como eliminar un nodo cuando hay mas de dos nodos
si elimino el segundo el archivo se me daña

Answer (score 0):

```
void eliminar(ldat &list)
```

{

```
ldat lis1;
ldat lis2=NULL;
char auxi[50];
int vcod;
char resp;
int posi=0;
int posj=0;
int band=0;
int ban1=0;
int dato=0; //CODIGO DEL    PRODUCTO A BUSCAR

pantalla(list);
poscf(3,10);printf("ELIMINACION DE DATOS");
poscf(3,12);printf("Codigo a eliminar.........: ");
gets(auxi);
dato=atoi(auxi);
lis1=list;
while((lis1!=NULL )&& (band==0))
{
    if(dato==lis1->codi)
    {
        poscf(3,14);printf(" Codigo...................: %i",list->codi);
        poscf(3,15);printf(" Descrpcion...............: %s",list->desc);
        poscf(3,16);printf(" Estado...................: %c",list->esta);
        
        
        band=1;
        
        poscf(3,27);printf("Esta seguro de eliminar el registro S(si) o N (No)");
        resp=toupper(getch());   //tolower()
        if(resp=='S')      //if(resp=='S' ||resp=='s')
        {
            
            if(ban1>0)
            {//se elimina cualquier nodo menos el 1ro
                lis2->sigu=lis1->sigu;
                delete(lis1);
            }
            else
            {//se elimina el 1er nodo
                
                if(lis1->sigu==NULL)
                {
                    delete(lis1);
                    list=NULL;
                }
                else
                {
                    //list=list;
                    //lis2=lis1->sigu;
                    delete(lis1);
                }
                
            }
            guardar_dato(lis1);
            poscf(3,27);printf("Registro eliminado con exito.....                       ");
            poscf(3,28);printf("presione cualquier tecla para continuar                 ");
            getch();
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        lis2=lis1;
        ban1++;
    }
    lis1=lis1->sigu;
}
if(band==0)
{
    printf("\n DATO A BUSCAR NO EXISTE!!!!");
}
```

}